# File comparison: Character level compare with side-by-side merge functionalities

Tags: windows, diff, comparison, file-merging, merge

I am looking for a software or other solution where I can compare text files at the character level and have a side-by-side view where I can apply changes (on the character level!) from one side to the other with a mouse click. In all the programs I have tried, you can only accept complete lines.

My current solution is to compare the documents with ABBY Fine Reader and save the changes as a Word file with tracking. Then I can accept or reject the respective changes in Word. Unfortunately, this is very confusing because the alternatives are right next to each other in the text and one of them is crossed out. One must then always look very closely, which makes the procedure error-prone. A side-by-side view would be much better.

It doesn't have to be a free software/solution and I don't have a specific price constraint.

Comment: Good question. Do you have an OS preference? If so, please update your question with the appropriate tag(s).  Also, if you have price constraints, please add them to your post.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you check if you could use `diff`? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff Maybe one of these can also help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools